# ¿Cómo saber cuántas palabras acaban con cierto string?

Tags: javascript

Dada una secuencia de palabras separadas por comas y finalizada por un punto, indica el número de palabras terminadas en ar, er, ir.
Ejemplo:
Entrada: correr,casa,saltar,subir,dormir,perro,comer,pez.
Resultado: Hay 8 palabras: 1 terminada en ar; 2 terminada(s) en er y 2 terminada(s) en ir.

Comment: Puedes añadir lo que has intentado hasta el momento? Mira [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Otra posible solución es el uso de regex con el método `match`.

```js
let input = "correr,casa,saltar,subir,dormir,perro,comer,pez.";

const er_count = input.match(/(\w*er\.?\b)+/g).length;
const ar_count = input.match(/(\w*ar\.?\b)+/g).length;
const ir_count = input.match(/(\w*ir\.?\b)+/g).length;

// Si alguno es undefined, simplemente igualarlo con cero

console.log('Conteo de palabras que terminan con (er): ',er_count);
console.log('Conteo de palabras que terminan con (ar): ',ar_count);
console.log('Conteo de palabras que terminan con (ir): ',ir_count);
```

Lo primero sería eliminar el punto del final, yo utilizaría la `slice` que devuelve la misma cadena sin el último elemento, después con `split` separaría la cadena de entrada en un arreglo, tomando como referencia las comas, y así podría utilizar sobre ese arreglo `filter`, que itera sobre ese array evaluando una condición dada sobre cada elemento, en este caso si la cadena termina con un valor determinado, devolviendo un nuevo array con todos elementos que cumplieron la condición, finalmente con la propiedad `lenght` obtendría el tamaño del arreglo o lo que es lo mismo, el número de elementos que cumplieron la condición.

```js
let input = "correr,casa,saltar,subir,dormir,perro,comer,pez.";

// Remover el punto al final
input = input.slice(0, -1); 

const arrayInput = input.split(',');
console.log(arrayInput);

const ar_count = arrayInput.filter( palabra => palabra.endsWith('ar')).length;

console.log('conteo de palabras terminadas en ar:' , ar_count);

const ir_count = arrayInput.filter( palabra => palabra.endsWith('ir')).length;

console.log('conteo de palabras terminadas en ir:' , ir_count);

const er_count = arrayInput.filter( palabra => palabra.endsWith('er')).length;

console.log('conteo de palabras terminadas en er:' , er_count);
```

**Edit**: Por cierto el método `endsWith()` evalúa si una cadena termina con un determinado valor.

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo te faltó explicar lo que hace `endsWith()`, que es la parte más importante.